# Issue with timing of Cache removal from server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I am trying to automate a process on my server. I want my program to run every 24 hours at 12:00:00 a.m. So I implemented the method suggested here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/07/18/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

When I run my program locally, it works fine (i.e. it runs at 12:00:00 a.m.) However, when I run the code on server, I see that the Cache is removed at random intervals (e.g. 7:44:03 PM, 6:48:08 AM, 1:33:47 PM, 4:50:35 PM, etc.) Is this because servers manage cache differently, or I'm missing something?

Here's my code in Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Some configuration here

    AddTask("NextRoundPreparer");
}

private void AddTask(string name)
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);

    OnCacheRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved);
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(name, name, null,
        tomorrow, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
        CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, OnCacheRemove);
}

public void CacheItemRemoved(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
{
    //Do some work here

    AddTask(key);
}
```

Comment: May be because App_start is occurring at different times and hence today.AddDays(1); adds to the current app start's DateTime?

Comment: Firstly, I dont know enough to know why app-start would start at different times. Moreover, even if it were to start at different times, I'm using Today and now Now +1 to get tomorrow's time. So in either case, wouldnt Cache be removed tomorrow exactly at 12:00 a.m.?